# HP 250 g6 Linux compatibility

Tags: hp, compatibility

Is HP 250 G6 compatible with Ubuntu? By default, it comes with Windows 10 and on www.support.hp.com I didn't find any linux drivers for it.
I still didn't buy this laptop and it's so important for me to find out this information.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is "HP 250 G6 i3-6006U 4G 500G 15.6", in [this site](https://www.pcubuntu.es/pcubuntu/6882090/hp-250-g6-i3-6006u-4g-500g-15-6%26quot%3B.html) they are selling it with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, this means that this laptop model is compatible with Ubuntu, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, those are its specs, only graphics is AMD Radeon 520.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you meet the recommended system requirements on the [ubuntu download page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) you should be good to go! Usually you wouldn't need any special drivers from HP, I think, unless you have another specific piece of hardware (like a printer) you're worried about.